# KendoUI Hierarchy Grid shows wrong data

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had a solution, similar to the following:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable:true,
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "address" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
          {
              name: "Beverages",
              address: "street 1",
              products: [
                { name: "Tea", price: 20 },
                { name: "Coffee", price: 23 }
              ]
          },
          {
              name: "Food",
              address: "street 2",
              products: [
                { name: "Ham", price: 32 },
                { name: "Bread", price:34 }
              ]
          }
    ],
    detailInit: function (e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: e.data.products,
            editable:true,
        });
    }
});
```

Those data I bring from sql server database.
The master data load correctly, but not the details. I do just what you see above. The first record I select go well (any record I select first, doesn't matter it's de first or last record in the grid). Then, any other go bad, or don't expand or show this error message "Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties". I could do a new database query and I guess that all be working fine, but is more efficient if I bring all data in the first request.

Any help it's welcome. Bye, Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this up...
It's complicated put the all scenario I have, so if anyone had a similar problem in his own scenario maybe this will help.

What I do was extract the datasource definition out of the grid definition.

```
   var ds = [
          {
              name: "Beverages",
              address: "street 1",
              products: [
                { name: "Tea", price: 20 },
                { name: "Coffee", price: 23 }
              ]
          },
          {
              name: "Food",
              address: "street 2",
              products: [
                { name: "Ham", price: 32 },
                { name: "Bread", price:34 }
              ]
          }
    ]   

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable:true,
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "address" }
    ],
    dataSource: ds,
    detailInit: function (e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: e.data.products,
            editable:true,
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this can help you.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted is not valid JavaScript. You need to modify it like this:

### OLD

```
/* snip */
columns: [
  { field: "name" },
  { field: "address" }
],
[
      {
          name: "Beverages",
/* snip */
```

### NEW

```
/* snip */
columns: [
  { field: "name" },
  { field: "address" }
],
dataSource: [
      {
          name: "Beverages",
/* snip */
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/oKiKupi/1/edit

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes, you'll right. But that was just a wrong copy-pasted. I had it that way. I'm now trying to load details with remote data too, but I have de same issue. Now I'm really shocked. I expected go well in that way but the same thing happen.

Comment: Yes, that works, but it's not the real data I'm working to. Maybe is that. It's impossible pass here the data with I working to. I went  to edit my original question and see if I can bring closer enough my problem.